# matplotlib limit figure save size for PdfPages

Tags: python, pdf, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

The included code takes about 2 mins to run, and creates a 22 mb pdf. Is there a way to limit the size of each saved figure to a reasonable limit (i.e. 1 mb)?

I have checked fig.get_dpi(), and it reports 80, which should be a reasonable size for a 4" x 6" figure.

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

# This will be the basic way for me to save figures
pp = PdfPages('test.pdf')

# Simulate and plot random data
dr = 1
rMax = 300
rRange = np.arange(0, rMax, dr)
R, Z = np.meshgrid(rRange, rRange)
Y = randn(R.shape[0], R.shape[1])
fig, ax = subplots()
ax.pcolor(R, Z, Y, cmap='RdBu')

# Save figure and produce pdf
pp.savefig(fig)
pp.close()
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using `pcolor` rather than the faster `imshow?` In some cases, `pcolor` is really what is desired, but those cases are rare, in my opinion.

Comment: Wow, amazing, that fixed my problem. I was just using pcolor by habit, i guess.